# Python, pulling info from a dict made up of key, values in which the values are 3-tuples

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a MapReduce program that returns the results of the computation as a dict that looks like the following:

```
{'pods': (54802L, 25417L, 59877L), 'sash': (160573L, 97199L, 178836L), ...}
```

I am trying to pull the items in this dictionary to make use of the values in the 3-tuples, but I keep receiving an error `KeyError: 0` when trying to parse through the errors in the code shown below (specifically on this line `key, indicies = results[i]`)

```
bloomFilter = [False] * 200000
for i in range(0, len(results)):
    key, indicies = results[i]
    bloomFilter[indicies[1]] = True
    bloomFilter[indicies[2]] = True
    bloomFilter[indicies[3]] = True
```

What is the proper way to pull the information from the dict so that I can make use of the values in the 3-tuples?

Also, can I use `L` values as indicies in a array, or do I need to cast them to ints?

Comment: You're indexing your dictionary by int, but the keys are string ('pods' is the key, not 0)..

Comment: Ahhh, I see. This makes sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would iterate over the `results` dictionary like so:

```
for key in results:
    indices = results[key]
    bloomFilter[indices[0]] = True
    bloomFilter[indices[1]] = True
    bloomFilter[indices[2]] = True
```

Note also that the `indices` tuple is zero-indexed, meaning you'll need to extract the values starting with zero (not one) like the above code shows.

Comment: oops, on the indicies, thanks for that. The solution works very well thank you!

Comment: Or even `for key, indicies in results.items(): ...`.